# Google Sign In not being signed in when page refreshes (Polymer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer, google-signin

I'm implementing "Google Sign In" into my website to handle all user authentication etc.. I will have a back-end database that I use to store information against users to keep track of their profile and their actions etc..

I've followed the Google Developer documentation and have got a "Google Sign In" button on a web page and when this button is clicked I choose my account and am signed in and the `id_token` goes off and is authenticated with my back-end server successfully. The only problem I'm now having is that when I refresh the page the button is back to "Sign In" rather than staying signed in, is this normal behaviour or is there something I'm missing? I don't want users to have to have to sign in again whenever the page changes.

On a side note I have managed to store the `id_token` from successfully logging into Google in `localStorage` and then using this `id_token` to re-authenticate with the back-end server automatically (as you can see in the commented out code) but this doesn't obviously automatically change the status of the "Google Sign In" button which would confuse users on the client-side.

Can anyone shed any light on this problem please?

**Not signed in:**

[image]

**After signing in *(doesn't currently stay like this after a page refresh)*:**

[image]

**login.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/base.css"/> <!-- Base CSS -->
        <script src="./js/all.js"></script> <!-- All JavaScript file -->
        <script src="./js/Logger.class.js"></script> <!-- Logger class -->
        <script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="./js/gSignIn.js"></script>
        <!-- Polymer -->
        <script src="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script> <!-- Web Components Import -->
        <!-- Element Imports -->
        <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html"/>
        <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/google-signin/google-signin.html"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <google-signin id="gSignIn" client-id="--- REMOVED FOR PRIVACY ---" scopes="profile email openid"></google-signin>
        <a href="#" id="signOut">Sign Out</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**gSignIn.js:**

```
/**
 * Google Sign In JavaScript
 */

$(document).ready(function() {
    var logger = new Logger("gSignIn.js", false); // logger object
    var id_token = null;
    logger.log("Load", "Successful");

    // Try to automatically login
//    if (localStorage !== null) { // If local storage is available
//        if (localStorage.getItem("gIDToken") !== null) { // If the Google ID token is available
//            id_token = localStorage.getItem("gIDToken");
//            // Send off AJAX request to verify on the server
//            $.ajax({
//               type: "POST", 
//               url: window.api.url + "googleauth/verify/",
//               data: { "id_token": id_token },
//               success: function (data) {
//                   if (!data.error) { // If there was no error
//                       logger.log("Google SignIn", "Successfully signed in!");
//                   }
//               }
//            });
//        }
//    }

    /**
     * EVENT: Google SignIn success
     */
    $("#gSignIn").on("google-signin-success", function () {
       id_token = getGoogleAuthResponse().id_token;
       var profile = getGoogleProfile();

       console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
       console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
       console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
       console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

       // Send off AJAX request to verify on the server
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST", 
          url: window.api.url + "googleauth/verify/",
          data: { "id_token": id_token },
          success: function (data) {
              if (!data.error) { // If there was no error
                  logger.log("Google SignIn", "Successfully signed in!");

                  // Store the id_token
                  if (localStorage !== null) { // If localStorage is available
                      localStorage.setItem("gIDToken", id_token); // Store the id_token
                  }
              }
          }
       });
    });

    $("#signOut").click(function () {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
          console.log("User signed out.");
        });
    });

    /**
     * Get Google Profile
     * 
     * @returns object
     */
    var getGoogleProfile = function () {
        var profile = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
        return profile;
    };

    /**
     * Get Google Auth Response
     * 
     * @returns object
     */
    var getGoogleAuthResponse = function () {
        var response = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse();
        return response;
    };
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and, after ensuring third party cookies were enabled, it came down to the hostname, `localhost` in this case.

In the end, I had to fake a domain using `/etc/hosts`, ensure google developers dashboard has that domain whitelisted, and start using that domain instead of localhost.

I can only assume that gapis don't like localhost, even though it's whitelisted in my google developers dashboard for the account I'm using. If you do manage to get `localhost` to work, do give me a shout!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that now :)

Comment: Thank you so much. No really, thank you! I was going crazy trying to figure this one out! I'd vote +1 ten times if I could!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to access localhost from a nonstandard port (not 80). I managed to get around this headache by using an nginx proxy from port 80 to 81:

```
server {
  listen 81;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
  }
}
```